# Inserir objeto de uma LinkedList para uma LinkedList de outra classe

Tags: java, lista, objetos, fila

Eu possuo duas classes em meu projeto: Carros e CarrosInativos.

Na primeira, tenho uma LinkedList declarada da seguinte forma:

```
private LinkedList<Carro> carros = new LinkedList<Carro>();
```

Em seguida, tenho métodos de inserção, exclusão e listagem. No entanto, precisei também implementar um método para receber objetos do tipo Carro a partir da classe que eu criei para implementar os métodos referentes aos carros com a situação de inativo. Este método simplesmente recebe um objeto o insere no final da LinkedList da minha classe Carros.

```
public void alocaCarros(Carro carro) {
        this.carros.add(carro);
    }
```

Na minha classe CarrosInativos possuo uma LinkedList para guardar os carros em situação de inatividade:

```
private LinkedList<Carro> carrosInativos = new LinkedList<Carro>();
```

Para realizar a inclusão desses carros inativos na lista de carros ativos quando necessário, invoquei a classe Carros dentro da classe CarrosInativos.

```
Carros carrosAtivos = new Carros();
```

Dentro dessa classe, possuo o método responsável por passar os objetos inseridos na fila de carros inativos para o método alocaCarros:

```
public void InsereCarros(){
carrosAtivos.alocaCarros(carrosInativos.getFirst());
                carrosInativos.remove();
}
```

Eis que surge o problema: nos testes, tanto a minha lista de carros ativos quanto a lista de carros inativos estão recebendo objetos normalmente; no entanto, ao invocar o método, não é realizada a inserção do objeto passado.

OBS.: Ao inserir um System.out.println na classe alocaCarros usando como parâmetro o objeto recebido, o objeto é listado normalmente na saída.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, ficou meio confuso para mim a explicação mas tentei rodar em cima do que você pediu.
Aqui funcionou certinho. Da uma olhada nas minhas classes e vê se consegue te ajudar nisso.
Ahhh eu faria diferente, criaria uma classe Carro e deixaria um atributo boolean para ativo. Pense nisso depois, acho que ficaria melhor.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class CarrosInativos {

private LinkedList<Carro> carrosInativos = new LinkedList<Carro>();

private Carros carrosAtivos = new Carros();

public void InsereCarros() {
    carrosAtivos.alocaCarros(carrosInativos.getFirst());
    carrosInativos.remove();
}

// Adicionei para poder inserir na classe de testes.
public void add(Carro carro) {
    this.carrosInativos.add(carro);
}

// Adicionei para poder recuperar na classe de testes
public LinkedList<Carro> getCarrosInativos() {
    return carrosInativos;
}

public Carros getCarrosAtivos() {
    return this.carrosAtivos;
}

 }

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Carros {

private LinkedList<Carro> carros = new LinkedList<Carro>();

public void alocaCarros(Carro carro) {
    this.carros.add(carro);
}

// Adicionei para poder recuperar na classe de testes.
public LinkedList<Carro> getCarros() {
    return carros;
} 

   }


public class TestaCarro {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Carro carro = new Carro("amarelo");
    Carro carro2 = new Carro("azul");
    Carro carro3 = new Carro("verde");

    CarrosInativos carrosInativos = new CarrosInativos();

    carrosInativos.add(carro);
    carrosInativos.add(carro2);
    carrosInativos.add(carro3);

    for ( Carro c : carrosInativos.getCarrosInativos()) {
        System.out.println(c);          
    }

    carrosInativos.InsereCarros();
    System.out.println("--------------");
    for ( Carro c : carrosInativos.getCarrosInativos()) {
        System.out.println(c);          
    }

    System.out.println("----");
    for ( Carro c : carrosInativos.getCarrosAtivos().getCarros()) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }

}
  }
```